# Not able to start Sonar Qube server on win10

Tags: sonarqube

I'm new to sonar qube and not able to integrate my spring boot application with sonar qube and getting below error when trying to start startsonar.bat from bin folder

```
C:\sonarqube-7.4\bin\windows-x86-64>StartSonar.bat
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
jvm 1    |
jvm 1    | 2018.12.07 19:14:41 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory C:\sonarqube-7.4\temp
jvm 1    | 2018.12.07 19:14:41 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
jvm 1    | 2018.12.07 19:14:41 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [C:\sonarqube-7.4\elasticsearch]: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\java -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -server -Xss1m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -Djdk.io.permissionsUseCanonicalPath=true -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0 -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true -Dlog4j.skipJansi=true -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Delasticsearch -Des.path.home=C:\sonarqube-7.4\elasticsearch -cp lib/* org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch -Epath.conf=C:\sonarqube-7.4\temp\conf\es
jvm 1    | 2018.12.07 19:14:41 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
jvm 1    | 2018.12.07 19:14:41 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
jvm 1    | 2018.12.07 19:14:41 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
jvm 1    | 2018.12.07 19:14:48 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractProcessMonitor] Process exited with exit value [es]: 1
jvm 1    | 2018.12.07 19:14:48 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [es] is stopped
jvm 1    | 2018.12.07 19:14:48 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll find the error message in one of the four main log files in _$SONARQUBE_HOME/logs_.

[The docs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/setup/troubleshooting/) have more details on what goes into each log, and how to read them.